# Azure Function Docker not working with http trigger

Tags: azure, docker, azure-functions

Recently I have created a docker image with Azure Function (Node) having HttpTrigger. This is a basic HttpTrigger which generate by default. I'm developing this on Macbook Pro (MoJave) and I have following tools installed.

NodeJs - node/10.13.0
.NET Core 2.1 for macOS
Azure Function core tools (via brew)

When I run the function locally with "func host start", it all works fine and I could see the function loading messages. Also I was able to execute the Azure function with trigger endpoint.However, when I try to build the Docker container and run the same, I can load the home page of the app but could not reach the function endpoint. In the log I could only see following;

```
Hosting environment: Production
Content root path: /
Now listening on: http://[::]:80
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
```

My Docker file is as below (generated by Azure core tools);

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/node:2.0
ENV AzureWebJobsScriptRoot=/home/site/wwwroot
COPY . /home/site/wwwroot
```

When I try to to use 'microsoft/azure-functions-runtime:v2.0.0-beta1' as base image, then I can see the function loading and could able to access the http trigger also.

Is there anything missing or do I need to use a different image?

Comment: Does my solution work for you? If so could you accept it for others to refer? Otherwise feel free to ask any further question.

Comment: Hi Jerry, Sorry could not reply you before. Yes it worked as a charm :) Thanks for pointing out to the function security configuration & logging console setting. Logging console setting is really useful. Cheers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. In Dockerfile,  add `ENV AzureFunctionsJobHost__Logging__Console__IsEnabled=true` to enable logging, the setting is [omitted in the basic image](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/3469#issuecomment-429183447) so we have to do it manually for now.
2. If you got 401 Unauthorized, find the file function.json, change authLevel to `anonymous` if it was `function`(default value in template). We can't access http trigger in a local container with authlevel other than `anonymous`. Because we don't have [function keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook#authorization-keys) yet, which are available after we create a Function app using the container.

   As for why we can access http trigger with `function` authlevel when we use `func host start` out of container, authorization is disabled regardless of the specified authentication level when running locally.

Comment: Recently had this problem