# How to use imported scripts needing DOM and window in Javascript/Node.js Azure Function

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure-functions, jsdom

I'm trying to use external javascript in an Azure Function (the javascript/node.js flavour).   Since the external javascript (I need to use kendo) depends on a DOM and a window, I tried to use JSDOM (but I don't have to use JSDOM if there is some better/easier alternative).

This is a simplified example of what I have:

```
module.exports = async function (context, req) {
    context.log('JavaScript HTTP trigger function processed a request.');

    var html = '<!DOCTYPE html>'
    + '<html>'
    +   '<head>'
    +       '<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>'
    +       '<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.2.514/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>'
    +   '</head>'
    +   '<body>'
    +       '<script>'
    +           'var myDiv = document.createElement("div");'        
    +           'myDiv.innerHTML = "Hello World";'
    +           'document.body.appendChild(myDiv);'
    +       '</script>'
    +   '</body>'
    + '</html>'
    ;

    var jsdom = require('jsdom');
    const { JSDOM } = jsdom;

    const dom = new JSDOM(html, {
        runScripts: "dangerously",
        resources: "usable"
    });

    var test = dom.serialize();
    context.log(test);

    context.res = {
        body: test
    };
};
```

When running this Azure function it should include jquery and kendo and create a div containing "Hello World". This is not working though.

The script creating the Hello World div is only executed if I comment out either

```
+       '<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>'
+       '<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.2.514/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>'
```

or

```
resources: "usable"
```

but then I cannot use jquery and kendo.

According to this jsdom [documentation](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom#loading-subresources) the parameter resources: "usable" should do the trick but for some reason it is not working.

I am using "jsdom": "^15.1.1"

**UPDATE**:
I tried a workaround adding the scripts like this:

```
module.exports = async function (context, req) {
    context.log('JavaScript HTTP trigger function processed a request.');

    var html = '<!DOCTYPE html>'
    + '<html>'
    +   '<head>'
    +   '</head>'
    +   '<body>'
    +       '<script>'
    +           'var myDiv = document.createElement("div");'        
    +           'myDiv.innerHTML = "Hello World";'
    +           'document.body.appendChild(myDiv);'
    +           'var scriptTag = document.createElement("script");'        
    +           'scriptTag.innerHTML = window.jqueryString;'
    +           'document.head.appendChild(scriptTag);'
    +       '</script>'
    +   '</body>'
    + '</html>'
    ;

    var jsdom = require('jsdom');
    const { JSDOM } = jsdom;

    var fs = require("fs");
    global.jqueryString = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '//jquery.js').toString();
    //context.log(jqueryString);

    const dom = new JSDOM(html, {
        runScripts: "dangerously"
    });

    var test = dom.serialize();
    context.log(test);


    context.res = {
        body: test
    };
};
```

This is adding a script tag to the header but the innerHTML is "undefined" instead of the jqueryString.
Outside of JSDOM (see the commented out line) logging jqueryString displays the content of jquery.js as expected. But inside of JSDOM that variable seems not to be available.  How can I pass jqueryString to JSDOM?

Comment: What OS did you selected for your Azure Function when you created it? Windows or LInux?

Comment: I kept the default which is Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the input of @PeterPan I managed to solve my problem using a [Docker based Azure function](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/azure-functions/functions-create-function-linux-custom-image.md) with **[Puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer)**.

Init Docker based FunctionApp:

`func init MyFunctionProj --docker` (select -> node -> javascript)

Edit MyFunctionProj\Dockerfile to use [estruyf/azure-function-node-puppeteer](https://github.com/estruyf/azure-function-node-puppeteer) and fs :

```
FROM estruyf/azure-function-node-puppeteer
RUN npm i fs
COPY . /home/site/wwwroot
```

Add fs to dependencies in MyFunctionProj\package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "fs": "0.0.1-security"
  }
```

Create HttpTrigger Function:

```
cd MyFunctionProj
func new --name MyHttpTrigger --template "HttpTrigger"
```

Grant Access to function:

Set `"authLevel": "anonymous"` in MyFunctionProj\MyHttpTrigger\function.json (for reason see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53412259/azure-function-docker-not-working-with-http-trigger).)

Create MyFunctionProj\MyHttpTrigger\content.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>ContentHtml</title>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.2.514/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
       var myComputationResult = .... // use included scripts to perform computation
       $("#resultData").html(JSON.stringify(myComputationResult));
    });
</script>
<div id="resultData"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Edit Function Logic in MyFunctionProj\MyHttpTrigger\index.js (based on [this](https://github.com/estruyf/azure-function-node-puppeteer#using-puppeteer)):

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const fs = require("fs");

module.exports = async (context, req) => {    
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        args: [
            '--no-sandbox',
            '--disable-setuid-sandbox'
        ]
    });

    var contentHtml = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '//content.html', 'utf8');

    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(`data:text/html,${contentHtml}`, { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });
    const resultData = await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector('#resultData').innerHTML);
    await browser.close();

    context.res = {
        // status: 200, /* Defaults to 200 */
        body: `Result: ${resultData}`
    };
};
```

Build docker image:

```
docker build --tag <docker-id>/mydockerimage:v1.0.0 .
```

Run docker image:

```
docker run -p 8080:80 -it <docker-ID>/mydockerimage:v1.0.0
```

Test local Function image in browser:

```
http://localhost:8080/api/MyHttpTrigger
```

Push image to Docker Hub:

```
docker login --username <docker-id>
docker push <docker-id>/mydockerimage:v1.0.0
```

Create a new Azure Function online and use image from Docker Hub as described [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/azure-functions/functions-create-function-linux-custom-image.md#create-a-linux-app-service-plan).

Answer (score 1):

I inspected the `jsdom` node package carefully, then I found that the feature [`Loading subresources`](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom#loading-subresources) required a headless browser like headless Chrome via [`karma`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma). However, due to the [`Win32k.sys (User32/GDI32) Restrictions`](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#win32ksys-user32gdi32-restrictions) of `Azure Web App sandbox`, it will never works fine as you wish on Azure App Service for Windows, because headless browser requires `GDI` support.

[image]

So I recommended that you need to migrate your function to Azure Functions for Linux (it's based on Docker Container) via rebuild it by [`Azure Functions Core Tools`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local#v2) as the offical document [`Create your first function hosted on Linux using Core Tools and the Azure CLI (preview)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-first-azure-function-azure-cli-linux) said. Or you have to use Windows, Azure Windows VM will be your best choice.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I will try to get it to work with a Linux Azure Function and let you know if I got it to work.

Comment: I created both of my function variants described above as Linux Azure Functions but unfortunately neither one is working.  The Linux variants are behaving the same as the Windows variants with the exact same errors.

Comment: @René Did you pre-install a chrome or chromium instance in your image?

Comment: I got it to work with a Docker based Linux Azure Function using Puppeteer.  I'll post a full answer here later on. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: @René Great! While Puppeteer be installing, a headless chromium will also be installed.